# Using anonymous PHP function as variable in Laravel callback

Tags: php, function, laravel, laravel-4

I'm running the following code in Laravel to load various relationships on my `Product` model:

```
$product->load([
        'skus' => function($query){

                $query->select($this->skuFields)->with([

                        'uniqueItem' => function($query){
                                // <----------reuse the code below--------->
                                $query->with([
                                        'fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems',
                                        'products' => function($query){

                                                $query->select($this->productFields)->with([
                                                        'skus' => function($query){
                                                                $query->select($this->skuFields);
                                                        }
                                                ]);
                                        },
                                        'skus' => function($query){
                                                $query->select($this->skuFields);
                                        }
                                ]);
                               // <----------reuse the code above--------->
                        }
                ]);
        },
        'uniqueItem' => function($query) {

                //need to reuse code here
        },
]);
```

As you can see from my note in the code, there is a place where I would like to reuse some code, so I was hoping to place it in a function, and reuse it.

Therefore, I did the following:

```
$uniqueItemLoadFunction = function($query)
{

        $query->with([
                'fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems',
                'products' => function($query){

                        $query->select($this->productFields)->with([
                                'skus' => function($query){
                                        $query->select($this->skuFields);
                                }
                        ]);
                },
                'skus' => function($query){
                        $query->select($this->skuFields);
                }
        ]);
};

$product->load([
            'skus' => function($query) use ($uniqueItemLoadFunction){

                    $query->select($this->skuFields)->with([

                            'uniqueItem' => $uniqueItemLoadFunction($query)
                    ]);
            },
            'uniqueItem' => function($query) {

                    //need to reuse code here
            },
    ]);
```

However, I now receive a `BadMethodCallException`:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems()
```

This error was not occurring when the code was run the original way. This makes me think I am not using an anonymous function correctly.  How can I make this work?

Comment: in your case, there is other error, message is saing, that in product model does not exist `'fulfillmentCenterUniqueItems'` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way.
However: The `uniqueItem`-key expects a function. But you are actually calling the function right away and only give the retuned value back to the key (which is null in this case). When now laravel tries to execute the given function it tries to execute `null()` which is not possible.

Long story short: Remove the brackets

```
'uniqueItem' => $uniqueItemLoadFunction
```

This way you assign the reference of the function to the key, not the returned value.